# Change size of FloatingActionButton

Tags: material-design, flutter, floating-action-button

How do I change the size of a `FloatingActionButton`?

I've tried increasing the size of the icon, but it doesn't affect the surrounding circular shape. I've also tried wrapping the button in a `PreferredSize` widget, but this had no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the `FloatingActionButton` in a `Container`, specifying the width and height.

You can override the size of the icon to make it look more natural:

```
Container(
  width: 80.0,
  height: 80.0,
  child: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Icon(
      Icons.add,
      size: 30.0,
    ),
  ),
);
```

I was pleased to discover the notch size is adjusted accordingly if you are embedding this button in a `BottomAppBar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
          height: 46.0,
          width: 46.0,
          child: FittedBox(
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                 "your code"
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
              backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? Comparing it to the accepted answer, it looks like you are using a `FittedBox` - does that avoid the need to resize the icon as well?

Comment: Hi Duncan, 
Thanks for the question. Rather than using the size in the icon, use the FittedBox, it automatically resizes the child, in this case the icon, in the container. You can use various types of fit, there are more options.